# GotoAndStop in Adobe Animate

Tags: javascript, adobe-animate

So I'm very new at writing code and I'm having trouble trying to create a slideshow/book and I've got the next and prev button working. But I want to have Tabs on the side that when you click on them it will go to that frame that has the picture and stop. For example: click on table of contents and have it go to and stop on that frame.

How do I go about writing the code for that?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far and explain, why does not it work for you.